# How to slow down a jQuery circle progress bar animation without .animate()

Tags: jquery

I want to slow down the animation of a circle progress bar. It seems to animate at the default 400ms. I've searched on this site and online and the majority of the answers relate to .animate() (or CSS tricks), which you can see isn't used in the code below.

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {
  function animateElements() {
    $(".progressbar").each(function () {
      var elementPos = $(this).offset().top;
      var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();
      var percent = $(this).find(".circle").attr("data-percent");
      var percentage = parseInt(percent, 10) / parseInt(100, 10);
      var animate = $(this).data("animate");
      if (elementPos < topOfWindow + $(window).height() - 30 && !animate) {
        $(this).data("animate", true);
        $(this)
          .find(".circle")
          .circleProgress({
            startAngle: -Math.PI / 2,
            value: percent / 100,
            size: 180,
            thickness: 15,
            emptyFill: "#ededed",
            fill: {
              color: "green"
            }
          })
          .on(
            "circle-animation-progress",
            function (event, progress, stepValue) {
              $(this)
                .find("div")
                .text((stepValue * 100).toFixed(0) + "%");
            }
          )
          .stop();
      }
    });
  }

  animateElements();
  $(window).scroll(animateElements);
  $(document).unbind("scroll");
});
```

Here's the link to the entire code: https://jsfiddle.net/c786Lnr4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [jquery-circle-progress](https://github.com/kottenator/jquery-circle-progress) docs specify that an `animation` property can be set on the configuration object passed to the `.circleAnimation` method. The docs also say that for further information about this this `animation` config, one should refer to jQuery's [.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) - so it seems this library *is* leveraging `.animate()`. jQuery's `.animate()` takes a `duration` property, which is a value in milliseconds. Therefore, if you wanted your animation to take 5 seconds, you would add `animation: { duration: 5000 }` to your `circleProgress` config.

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {
  function animateElements() {
    $(".progressbar").each(function() {
      var elementPos = $(this).offset().top;
      var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();
      var percent = $(this).find(".circle").attr("data-percent");
      var percentage = parseInt(percent, 10) / parseInt(100, 10);
      var animate = $(this).data("animate");
      if (elementPos < topOfWindow + $(window).height() - 30 && !animate) {
        $(this).data("animate", true);
        $(this)
          .find(".circle")
          .circleProgress({
            animation: {
              duration: 5000
            },
            startAngle: -Math.PI / 2,
            value: percent / 100,
            size: 180,
            thickness: 15,
            emptyFill: "#ededed",
            fill: {
              color: "green"
            }
          })
          .on(
            "circle-animation-progress",
            function(event, progress, stepValue) {
              $(this)
                .find("div")
                .text((stepValue * 100).toFixed(0) + "%");
            }
          )
          .stop();
      }
    });
  }

  animateElements();
});
```

```css
.progressbar {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 25px;
}

.circle {
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.circle:after {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  content: "";
  /*border: 2px solid #fb4f14;*/
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 30px;
}

.circle canvas {
  vertical-align: middle;
  /*border: 2px solid #fb4f14;*/
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.circle div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -20px 0 0 -86px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-family: roboto;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: green;
}

.circle strong i {
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 0.6em;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.circle span {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-circle-progress/1.2.2/circle-progress.min.js"></script>
<div class="progressbar" data-animate="false">
  <div class="circle" data-percent="90">
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here is a [fork](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/29vcmfs6/) of your fiddle.

Comment: Thank you! I tried animation, but it didn't seem to work.